# Using Scrapy, getting "Error: ImportError: No module named testspiders.spiders.followall"

Tags: python, node.js, scrapy

I am trying to  run Scrapy from a script, and have been following the tutorial [here](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/0.24/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script). I am running into an error message that states `Error: ImportError: No module named testspiders.spiders.followall`. I have been looking around for a solution, but haven't found a match yet.

I am actually running this python script through node.js, which has a module named [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.org/package/python-shell), which simply allows you to run a python script using the following simple code:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

PythonShell.run('my_script.py', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

Verbatim, my code is copied from the scrapy website:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from testspiders.spiders.followall import FollowAllSpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

spider = FollowAllSpider(domain='scrapinghub.com')
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

My directory structure has only been modified from the [express framework](http://expressjs.com/) by my addition of the python directory and file, as well as the few lines of code that utilize python-shell:

```
-python-node
    -bin
    -node_modules
    -public
    -python 
        -my_script.py
    -routes
    -views
    -app.js
    -package.json
```

NOTE: This also does not work if I go into the python directory and run `python my_script.py`, and I get the same error message: `ImportError: No module named testspiders.spiders.followall`

Comment: Could you show your current directory structure? Thanks.

Comment: In a python shell, can you do `import testspiders`, `from testspiders import spiders`, etc. ?

Comment: It doesn't work for those, but all of the other imports work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when running crawler with `scrapy`, then scraper root dir (parent dir of testspiders/) is added to the path automatically. When running a script with `python` this is not the case. You have working directory and whatever is defined in PATH and PYTHONPATH there.

You can check current path in python with `sys.path`

So to make import statements working with `python` you can:

- add testspiders/ parent dir to path with sys.path.append() (have to do it before the import testspiders... statement)
- add parent dir to PYTHONPATH system variable
- run `python` command from parent dir of testspiders/
- edit import statements (so they work according to your PATH)

Comment: Can you add an example of how you would do the first example?